# How to make a function that takes 4 arguments and can be called with even 2 or 3 parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dom

I have a function that receives 4 arguments but the second and the third argument are optional.
I need it to be called with the first and the last parameter and skip the the second and the third withoud overwriting the default value.

Here is the code

```js
export default function useSetDefaultActiveMenu(currentState,stateValue="", selector="", value) {
    //checking id the currentState
    if (currentState === stateValue)
      document
        .querySelector(`[${selector}="${value}"]`)
        .classList.add(activeItem);
}
```

I want to call it like this :

```js
useSetDefaultActiveMenu("someItem","something else")
```

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Just check the arguments at the beginning of the function with if/then/else if/else logic. If a parameter is null (if !param), you know to proceed to the version of the function that doesn't use it.

Comment: when I call the function with 2 params it overwrites the second arg's default value. I need it to make the 2nd and 3rd param optional without overwritting  their values

Comment: To call the function and skip a parameter, you either have to leave a "gap" (i.e. `foo(13,,true)`) where the unsupplied parameter would be or make it so each parameter is a different type so that you can test the types being passed to know which arguments are being passed.

Comment: It works, thanks. Bu the way, is what I wanted even possible  to make? Like how i needed to call it?

Comment: I'm confused. Yes it's possible. My above comments describe how to make and call it.

Answer (score 0):

how about a helper function
so first declare a helper function that takes two parameters

```
useSetDefaultActiveMenuHelper(currentState,value) {
useSetDefaultActiveMenu("someItem",'','',"something else")
}
```

now instead of calling the original method you now call the helper which will call the original
note that if you want to put the optional you need to call the original method not the helper

Answer (score 0):

1. You can pass **undefined** instead of second and third optional parametrs;

```
      useSetDefaultActiveMenu("someItem", undefined, undefined,"something else");
```

Comment: yeah this works but i need to event not pass the undefined as parameter, to just pass the first and the last but keep the 2nd and the 3rd with their default values

Comment: You don't even need to pass `undefined`. You could just do: `foo("test",,,true)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's typical to put required parameters before the optional ones. If for some reason, this isn't possible, you can check to see how many arguments you got and set the values into the correct variables.

```js
function useSetDefaultActiveMenu(currentState, ...args) {
  let stateValue = "";
  let selector = "";
  let value;
  switch (args.length) {
    case 1: 
      value = args.shift();
      break;
    case 2:
      stateValue = args.shift();
      value = args.shift();
      break;
    case 3:
      stateValue = args.shift();
      selector = args.shift();
      value = args.shift();
      break;
    default:
      throw new Error("Invalid number of args.");
  }
  /* ... other stuff */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide some default values to the parameters you wanted to be optional. Such as:

```
export default function useSetDefaultActiveMenu(currentState,stateValue="", selector="", value) {
//checking id the currentState
if (currentState === stateValue)
document
  .querySelector(`[${selector}="${value}"]`)
  .classList.add(activeItem);
}
```

Comment: You do not "need" to provide default values to optional parameters.